# share same x axis on 2 different plotly dataframe histograms

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I would like to plot two historgrams for  2 different pandas dataframes, sharing same x-axis , using plotly cufflinks (or if it is not possible, just plotly)

following code plots 2 different plots, not sharing x-axis

```
 df1.iplot(kind='histogram')
 df2.iplot(kind='histogram')
```

i would like both histograms share same x-axis

Comment: consider passing `ax` to the `iplot` function.

Answer (score 6):

I think you looking for this:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import numpy as np

x0 = np.random.randn(500)
x1 = np.random.randn(500)+1

trace1 = go.Histogram(
    x=x0,
    opacity=0.75
)
trace2 = go.Histogram(
    x=x1,
    opacity=0.75
)

data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(barmode='overlay')
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig, filename='overlaid histogram')
```

Output:

[image: histograms]

Or you might create subplots with shared xaxis:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.offline as py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Histogram(
    x=np.random.randn(500)
)
trace2 = go.Histogram(
    x=np.random.randn(500)
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, specs=[[{}], [{}]],
                          shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=False,
                          vertical_spacing=0.001)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='Stacked Subplots with Shared X-Axes')
py.iplot(fig, filename='stacked-subplots-shared-xaxes')
```

Output:

[image: subplots]